# get process name for mongodb open connections

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I need to know process/file name of the open MongoDB connections.

for example, assume there are files called F1,F2 ..., Fn using Connection pool to get mongodb connection. each running in parallel in different process.

Is there any way to get file name which having open connection to mongodb.

Because, I am on mission to reduce number of open mongodb connections.

when I did below query,

```
db.serverStatus().connections
```

It giving me current consumed connections count, available count. But I need filenames which opened connection to optimize.

stack: python,django,some server running in apache, mongodb, pymongo

Answer (score 2):

I figured out myself how to know more about connections information.

```
db.currentOp(true).inprog
```

Above command will give all current connections information in array. you can see information such as client ip,whether its active or not,connection id,operation type and everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the connection details in the most rudimentary form using a quick shell command such as

> ps -eAf | grep mongo

If you use this command on the host running your mongod process. Essentially you can make a note of all active pid's and take corrective actions

Comment: this is not answering my question. I need to know mongo process which have open connections. this will only give pid of mongodb.